How to print a list of web elements in text format using Selenium
I have a list of elements that I would like to print in text format, However Selenium does not print it out in a readable format.
Below is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.morphmarket.com/all/c/reptiles/pythons/ball-pythons")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

snakes = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.animalCard--avL0R")))

links = []
for i in snakes:
     links.append(i.get_attribute("href"))
 

elements_details=[]
for link in links:

    driver.get(link)
    genes = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.animalTitle--cH6qE")))
    elements_details.append({"genes":genes})
    snake = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.animalSubTitle--mhYId")))
    elements_details.append({"snake":snake})
    price = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.salePrice--qNIIs")))
    elements_details.append({"price":price})

    Birth = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.labelValueContainer--z1CP3")))
    for birth in Birth:
        elements_details.append({"brith":birth})

    Company_info = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "(//  div[@class='infoWrapper--O_L9E'])[2]")))
    for element in Company_info:
        elements_details.append(element)
    print(elements_details)

I get the following results:
element.WebElement (session="43b60aaa3129f97d15914647fa4f1b8e", element="f.E7FC5A3BF156624EFE99B26EC569C38C.d.C9A57DDAB00D61F5D167966E0AC0616F.e.153")>}, {'brith': <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="43b60aaa3129f97d15914647fa4f1b8e", 


those are webelement references.... (class with methods and ref)  you might instead use get attribute method for outerHTML, innerHTML, or use text method there depending on what you want.

elements_details.append({"genes":genes})
elements_details.append({"snake": snake})
elements_details.append({"price": price})
elements_details.append({"brith": birth})
elements_details.append(element)

In the above lines of code, you are appending the web element object to the list. You should extract the text of the web element using .text method and then append it. Change the code as below:
elements_details.append({"genes":genes.text})
elements_details.append({"snake": snake.text})
elements_details.append({"price": price.text})
elements_details.append({"brith": birth.text})
elements_details.append(element.text)

Just another note: Make sure at the end, your print statement of the elements_details list is indented properly. Put it outside the for loop. In the code in your question it's within the for loop.
